# Jquery onclick function runs multiple time increasingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, onclick

I have interesting problem and i can't figure it out why it's happening like that. I have dataTables and data comes after selection change on a select, with jquery ajax post. And i have onclick function for multiple selection. (It must be run when click at table and it changes rows style etc.) I noticed that (with debug); when i click on row after first load onclick works one time as expected. But click **after second load (selection changed) it runs 2 time** and click **after third load it runs 3 time** i don't understand what's going on. So need some help.

Here is selection change function that loads the table;

```
// in doc.ready
$('#groupSelect').change(function() {
  var group = $('#groupSelect').val();

  if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#questTable')) //this is for first load
  {
    GetQuestions(group);
  } else //this is for after first load
  {
    var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    table.clear().draw();
    GetQuestions(group);
  }
});
```

And this is GetQuestions() function that gets data;

```
// out of doc ready
function GetQuestions(questGroup) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'SetAudit.aspx/Questions',
    data: '{"q_group":"' + questGroup + '"}',
    success: function(result) {
      $('#questTable').DataTable({
        data: result.d,
        columns: [{
          data: 'q_id'
        }, {
          data: 'q_text'
        }]
      });


      //this click function runs multiple time at 1 click
      $('#questTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
        var count = table.rows('.selected').count();
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('#selectedCount').text('' + table.rows('.selected').count() + '');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I don't if it is ok that i created it in ajax success func but it doesn't work anywhere else. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because every time a `change` event occurs on `#groupSelect` you fire an AJAX request, and in the `success` handler of that AJAX request you attach *another* `click` event handler to the `tr` of the table. Hence they duplicate.

To fix this I'd suggest you move the `tr` event handler outside the `success` handler and only run it once on load of the DOM. Try this:

```
function GetQuestions(questGroup) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'SetAudit.aspx/Questions',
        data: { q_group: questGroup },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#questTable').DataTable({
                data: result.d,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'q_id' },
                    { data: 'q_text' }
                ]
            });
        }
    });
}

// do this on load *only*
$('#questTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
    var count = table.rows('.selected').count();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $('#selectedCount').text(table.rows('.selected').count());
});
```

Comment: Yes sir i didn't like using this function in ajax success at the begining. But when i create it outside (like your answer) it doesn't run. I think my real problem is that. This onclick doesn't work anywhere else. What can i do?

Comment: Change the event handler signature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: It sounds like `#questTable tbody` may not be in the DOM when it loads. Try changing it to `$(document).on(...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you were right. I solved it with $(document).on() structure. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on   this article did really usefull to get it. And you make me understand the real problem. --Sorry for late response-- Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
 //this click function runs multiple time at 1 click
$('#questTable tbody').off().on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
  var count = table.rows('.selected').count();
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('#selectedCount').text('' + table.rows('.selected').count() + '');
});
```

There are multiple ways you can solve the issue.

**Removing and Adding the table DOM element**: It depends on the way you construct data table. If you are constructing your datatable only from JS then you can go with this approach.

```
// in doc.ready
$('#groupSelect').change(function() {
  var group = $('#groupSelect').val();

  if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#questTable')) {// this is for first load
    GetQuestions(group);
  } else {//this is for after first load
    var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    table.clear().draw();
    // empty the table which will eventually clear all the event handlers
    $('#questTable').empty();
    GetQuestions(group);
  }
});
```

**Using [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) event of datatable along with jQuery [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**: You can place the row highlighting function in `drawCallback`

```
//out of doc ready
function GetQuestions(questGroup) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'SetAudit.aspx/Questions',
    data: '{"q_group":"' + questGroup + '"}',
    success: function(result) {
      $('#questTable').DataTable({
        data: result.d,
        columns: [{
          data: 'q_id'
        }, {
          data: 'q_text'
        }],
        drawCallback: function(settings) {
          //this click function runs multiple time at 1 click
          $('#questTable tbody').off().on('click', 'tr', function() {
            var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
            var count = table.rows('.selected').count();
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $('#selectedCount').text('' + table.rows('.selected').count() + '');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I had been trying to use as you gived second section of your answer. I couldn't fire the onclick like that but now; i get it why and i've solved it with McCrossan's advice. Thank you for this usefull and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the binding to the `click` event inside your `.change()` function. This way you add a new binding everytime, hence the increasing number of calls to the function.

The proper way to do so is moving `$('#questTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {` outside of `GetQuestions`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I actually tryed it but i couldn't fire onclick anywhere else except ajax call, but now i understand why i couldn't and solved with McCrossan's advice. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `$('selector').on('click', ...)`, you're registering a new callback to execute when an element matching your selector is clicked. So in this case, every time that ajax call completes, you will register *another* click handler. So if your ajax call executes three times, you will have registered three identical click handlers, and all of them will execute.

You should make sure your `$('#questTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', ...)` is only executed once.

Comment: Yes you're right. I couldn't fire onclick anywhere else except ajax call, but now i understand why i couldn't and solved with McCrossan's advice. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have add new event listener after every ajax request, 
move click event from ajax callback

```js
//out of doc ready
function GetQuestions(questGroup) {
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType:'application/json',
  url:'SetAudit.aspx/Questions',
  data: '{"q_group":"' + questGroup + '"}',
  success: function (result) {
   $('#questTable').DataTable({
    data: result.d,
    columns: [
     { data: 'q_id' },
     { data: 'q_text' }
    ]
   });


  }
 });
}

//this click function runs multiple time at 1 click
$('#questTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
 var table = $('#questTable').DataTable();
 var count = table.rows('.selected').count();
 $(this).toggleClass('selected');
 $('#selectedCount').text('' + table.rows('.selected').count() + '');
});
```

Comment: I actually tryed this one but now i get my real problem and solved it with McCrossan's advice. But thank you for the answer.